# DjangOAuthToolkit - How to have different read/write scope for a View?

Tags: python, django, django-oauth

I'm using DRF and OAuthToolkit. Here is my view:-

```
class UserDetailView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [TokenHasResourceScope]
    required_scopes = ['user_detail']
```

Now, the above view will support `GET`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` methods. Now, if I create a token with a scope as `user_detail`, it will give access to all the methods. However, I want different read/write scopes for SAFE and UNSAFE methods.

Upon reading [OAuthToolkit](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/contrib/rest_framework/permissions.py#L99) code for `TokenHasResourceScope`, it create scopes for `SAFE` and `UNSAFE` methods, ie `user_detail:read` and `user_detail:write`.

Now, if the client request for `user_detail:read` scope, the library returns `invalid scope`.

How do I support scopes for read and write of a particular view differently?